# Iterating through DataSnapShot.Children stops the execution of code (Unity, Firebase)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a method that retrieves the data from Firebase in Unity (C#). I can successfully retrieve the data. But when I iterate through dataSnapShot.Children to assign values to my certain variables that are to be used in the game. The execution gets stopped. There is no error in Console.

```
public void GetUsers(List<User> users)
{
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
  .GetReference("users")
        .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
         {
                 if (task.IsFaulted) {
      // Handle the error...
                    Debug.Log("Error was:"+task.Exception.Message);
                    Debug.LogError("Error was:"+task.Result.Children);
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            // Do something with snapshot...
                        foreach(DataSnapshot s in snapshot.Children){
                        IDictionary dictUsers = (IDictionary)s.Value;   
                        Debug.Log(dictUsers["displayName"]);                    
                    }   
                    // After this foreach loop in snapshot.Children, nothing executes
                    UIManager.instance.ShowOtherUsers();
            }
  });
}
```

Comment: What does "the execution gets stopped" mean here? When you step through this code in a debugger, do you reach the `UIManager.instance.ShowOtherUsers()` line?

Comment: No I don't reach `UIManager.instance.ShowOtherUsers()`
And that's what I mean by "the execution gets stopped".

Comment: According to documentation, DataSnapshot.Children is of IEnumerable<DataSnapShot> type.
Maybe its because of that?

Comment: I honestly have no idea yet what works and what doesn't work about your code. Please be extremely explicit: if you put a breakpoint on `if (task.IsFaulted) {` does it get triggered? If you step through the code from there, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: In currenty case, task.IsCompleted is triggered. And hence the foreach loop inside it is also executed and stops logging after all the values are printed meaning the loop is ended. 
The next thing to be executed is the statement right after it which UIManager.instance.ShowOtherUsers() which is not being executed.
I'm sorry I'm making it difficult to understand.

Comment: I hope you understand the problem and can provide me some solution to that. 
Meanwhile I've also done some workaround and got it fixed. I'm adding that into the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow did a workraround to get it fixed. 
Actually the [SnapShot.Children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1ae4827fb6022f78793c8cfd2a9f6cc488) (by Firebase Unity SDK) is of IEnumerable. Type.
I searched through internet on [iterating](http://IEnumerable%3CT%3E%20mySequence;%20using%20(var%20sequenceEnum%20=%20mySequence.GetEnumerator())%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20while%20(sequenceEnum.MoveNext())%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Do%20something%20with%20sequenceEnum.Current.%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D) [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) collections. 
And then replaced my code from this :

```
else if (task.IsCompleted) {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
        // Do something with snapshot...
                    foreach(DataSnapshot s in snapshot.Children){
                    IDictionary dictUsers = (IDictionary)s.Value;   
                    Debug.Log(dictUsers["displayName"]);                    
                }   
                // After this foreach loop in snapshot.Children, nothing executes
                UIManager.instance.ShowOtherUsers();
        }
```

To this:

```
else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                // Do something with snapshot...

            using (var sequenceEnum = snapshot.Children.GetEnumerator())
            {
             for(int i = 0 ;i<snapshot.Children.Count();i++){
                while (sequenceEnum.MoveNext())
                {
                  try{
                      IDictionary dictUser =(IDictionary)sequenceEnum.Current.Value;

                      Debug.Log("displayName:"+dictUser["displayName"]);

                    }
                    catch(System.Exception e){
                        Debug.Log(e.Message);
                    }
                    Debug.Log("At The End!");
                UIManager.instance.ShowOtherUsers(); // Now it executes like a Charm 


         }
```

It worked like a Charm... What I understand is that this execution was being done a Threaded "Task". 
Although, I don't know exactly how is it working or why it was not working with my previous code. Someone, who can provide better information is welcome :)
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think its a mix of both, like when you initialize the SDK, how it is done in a thread that is not the main thread, if your internet conection is not good enough to keep the cpu pace, the main thread and the working thread enter in race conditions that cannot be follow up by the way unity monobehaviours works ( not at all multithreading friendly).

Remenber aswell the topyc about json formats allowed to do that, there is only a few native types supported.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you should try adding an example to help