# For-loop stops when calling function in Firebase for Unity C#

Tags: c#, firebase, loops, unity-game-engine

I have a similar issue as [Iterating through DataSnapShot.Children stops the execution of code (Unity, Firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232239/iterating-through-datasnapshot-children-stops-the-execution-of-code-unity-fire)
The solution to this question also helped me to get my code working. However I additionally wanted to call a function which creates a new GameObject every iteration of the for loop. The for loop seems to call the callForEachElement()-function on every iteration, if the function only includes a "Debug.Log" statement. As soon as I try to instantiate an object inside the function, the for loop stops after the first call and doesn't instantiate the object. In the code below Debug.Log("Before instantiation") is called and Debug.Log("After instantiation") is never called. Can anybody explain why this doesn't work and why the loop just runs one time, if I want to do this?

```
public GameObject prefab;

private void loadEntriesFromServer()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("202012").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
         {
             if (task.IsFaulted)
             {
                 // Handle the error...
                 Debug.Log("ERROR IN LOAD ENTRIES");
             }
             else if (task.IsCanceled)
             {
                 Debug.Log("Task was Cancelled");
             }
             else if (task.IsCompleted)
             {
                 DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

                 using (var sequenceEnum = snapshot.Children.GetEnumerator())
                 {
                     for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.Children.Count(); i++)
                     {
                         while (sequenceEnum.MoveNext())
                         {
                             try
                             {
                                 IDictionary dictUser = (IDictionary)sequenceEnum.Current.Value;
                                 Debug.Log("displayName:" + dictUser);
                                 callForEachElement();

                             }
                             catch (System.Exception e)
                             {
                                 Debug.Log(e.Message);
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         });


    void callForEachElement()
    {
        Debug.Log("Before instantiation");
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
        Debug.Log("After instantiation");
    }
```

Comment: `GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;` <-- Are you saying that this call hangs and never returns?

Comment: yes, correct. It looks like the line above -> `Debug.Log("Before instantiation");` is the last one being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `ContinueWith` runs on the main thread, and you can only safely `Instantiate` on the main thread.
Consider moving your instantiation loop outside the Task, or try the Firebase Extension `ContinueWithOnMainThread`, described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension).

ex.

```c#
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("202012").GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task
```

Comment: correct, it was the problem with the thread! thanks for the code example, worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

I looks like something you are doing in the `Instantiate(prefab)` statement may causing the task from `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("202012").GetValueAsync()` and its children to be cancelled.

Call the [ContinueWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_System_Object__System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskContinuationOptions_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_) method using a cancellation token so you can see if this is the case.

Info on [Task Canellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)